# How can I solve this following function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've Seen this following exercise in a book and there was no sample solution for that. I'm very new to functions of higher orders and i'm not sure how should i implement this function.I thought maybe you can give me some ideas.

I should implement a function `foldleft :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`, by that for every  is valid that:
`f :: a -> b -> a` and `a0 :: a,b1, …, bk :: b,k∈N` and `foldleft f a0 [b1, …, bk] = f (f … (f a0 b1) ⋯ bk−1)bk`
,

so for example:

```
foldleft(+) 5 [1, 4, 3] = (+) ((+) ((+) 5 1) 4) 3 = ((5 + 1) + 4) + 3
```

and in particular, it should apply : `foldleft f a [] = a`

Answer (score 1):

You can do pattern matching on the two data constructors of a list: the empty list, and the "cons" `(:)`, so:

```
foldleft :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldleft f z [] = …
foldleft f z (x:xs) = …
```

for the second clause you will need to apply `f` on `a` and the head of the list, and then use this as initial accumulator when recursing on the tail of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Start by breaking it into two cases:

```
foldleft f a0 [] = ...
foldleft f a0 (b1:b2_through_bk) = ...
```

Then look at the equations in your specification, and see which, if any, of them can help you start filling in the `...`s.